# Java scanner not working on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, input

The program compiles and runs, but it is not allowing me to input any value. The program just ends without letting me input anything. Why?

```
package prac;

import java.util.Scanner;

    public class prac {

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
            int number;
            System.out.println("Input number: ");
            number = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(number);


        }

    }
```

Comment: and by"not working" , you mean?

Comment: I was able to run your code successfully.

Comment: Ya it is working at my side too

Comment: It isn't letting me input any thing. Program just ends.

Comment: There has to be something else you're not telling us; the code appears to work as illustrated.  You're sure that you're compiling it correctly and running it correctly?

Comment: Where are you running your program?. IDE? cmd prompt?

Comment: Do you see the Input number prompt?

Comment: @user3324792 Try putting a *print* statement at the beginning and at the end. And tell us if both get displayed.

Comment: can u able to see the console screen in ur eclipse ??? if not open the  console screen once compiled and exceuted ur program

Comment: Nope.. I'm not seeing console screen. The code I posted is all there is. I've restarted eclipse but still no change. Could it be something to with not seeing the console?

Comment: So, there is NO CONSOLE or the CONSOLE is not SHOWING ANYTHING?

Comment: " I'm not seeing console screen" goto Window--> Show View --> Console

Comment: Once u have run ur application ,press  alt+shift+q c , u can find the console screen in eclipse..

Comment: Yes that was the issue - NO CONSOLE!

Answer (score 3):

Your probably not getting focus on the console.  AFter you run the java program switch to the console.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a close statement for Scanner

try:

```
number = input.nextInt();
in.close();
```

Answer (score -3):

I believe what's happening is (I may be wrong) it is executing all the code and then closing so fast that you couldnt possibly input anything.

Comment: scanner waits for your input

Answer (score -3):

If you want to give arguments on RunTime , right click on java file go to Run AS -> run configurations and you can pass arguments by clicking Arguments Tab ,using program variables option